# SQL Left Join and Conditions

Tags: sql, left-join

```
SELECT 
    A.RowId
FROM 
    dbo.Rows A
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SpecialRows B ON A.RowId = B.RowId AND B.ExcludeRowId > 0
WHERE
    A.FileId = 55
    AND A.Active = 1
    AND A.ExcludeRowId = 0
    AND B.RowId IS NULL /* This is to perform EXCEPT like operation */
```

Friends, this is my query and I have a few questions related.

Q1) Let's say I have another query same as this one except first 3 where conditions are moved to ON clause of LEFT JOIN.
Will it generate same result set?

Q2) In general, if I use LEFT JOIN then all conditions related to the right side table (which is dbo.SpecialRows in this case) must be in ON clause, is this correct?

Q3) Also if I put conditions related to the left side table (which is dbo.Rows in this case) in either WHERE clause or ON clause then the result set will be same, is this correct?

Please explain, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Question 1

- No, it will have a different result set.
- You will get all the rows of A and only the rows of B where all the conditions are met

Question 2

- Generally yes. There are opinions that maybe there are certain cases otherwise.
- If you are not careful, you can turn a LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN if you put a condition checking a value in the WHERE clause not accounting for the NULL condition

Question 3

- See question 1 answer for details
- If conditions on A are in WHERE, then you only get rows of A matching those conditions regardless of impact of B
- If conditions on A are in ON, then you get all rows of A and then only rows of B matching the conditions in the ON even if they are only against A

Comment: I believe question 1 is correct. I setup a SQLFiddle to show how the 2 scenarios return different row counts - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d45b/5/0.